# How to get full host name in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, dns, environment-variables, mdns

I have tried by following by it just give me single name. I want full name.
Ex. my system full name is "**sys101.home.homeconsultancy.lan**". Following code gives me just "**sys101**". I want full address "**sys101.home.homeconsultancy.lan**".

Here is my code:

```
string hostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
```

How can I get full system name?

Comment: What do you mean *"full host name"*? Do you mean the DNS name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostentry#System_Net_Dns_GetHostEntry_System_String_):

```
var fullName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(string.Empty).HostName;
```

> If an empty string is passed as the `hostNameOrAddress` argument, then this method returns the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses of the local host.

Comment: Please read [Interpolated Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx)